# punctuation system in django

Tags: django

My question is where I can find a voting system of thumbs.

I have searched and most is in php, but I need it in python.

I am using the django framework, I am new in this framework and was wondering if anyone has used a system punctuation with thumbs, I need to qualify a new video post

Answer (score 0):

This might worth a look http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/wiki/RedditStyleVoting. Also you can search on StackOverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=voting+python